# Cannot create an all day event series into google calendar, from google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, scripting, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I have been trying for days now, reading other posts, playing with other scripts that have been close to the same purpose and nothing works.  I am trying to make a script that will take information from a web based google form, along with a month/day and turn it into a re-occuring event in the Calendar.

It is finally posting to the Calendar NOW but every event comes up undefined under December 31, 2015 - with no further information, altho at least it is reoccurring.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I try to understand this coding and how to do it.  Thank you!

```
//this is the ID of the calendar to add the event to, this is found on the calendar settings page of the calendar in question
var calendarId = "id@group.calendar.google.com";

//below are the column ids of that represents the values used in the spreadsheet (these are non zero indexed)
var startDtId = 5;
var endDtId = 5;
var titleId = 2;
var descId = 3;
var formTimeStampId = 1;

function getLatestAndSubmitToCalendar() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();
  var lr = rows.getLastRow();
  var startDt = sheet.getRange(lr,startDtId,1,1).getValue();
  //set to first hour and minute of the day.
//  startDt.setHours(0);
//  startDt.setMinutes(00);
  var endDt = sheet.getRange(lr,endDtId,1,1).getValue();
  //set endDt to last hour and minute of the day
//  endDt.setHours(23);
//  endDt.setMinutes(59);
//  var subOn = "Submitted on :"+sheet.getRange(lr,formTimeStampId,1,1).getValue();
  var desc = sheet.getRange(lr,descId,1,1).getValue();
  var title = sheet.getRange(lr,titleId,1,1).getValue();
  createAllDayEvent(calendarId,title,startDt,endDt,recurrence,loc,desc);
}​

  function createAllDayEventSeries(calendarId,title,startDt,endDt,recurrence,loc,desc) {
  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('id@group.calendar.google.com');
  var start = new Date(startDt);
  var end = new Date(endDt);
  var loc = descId;
  var desc = "Happy Birthday "+titleId+" of "+descId;
// Creates a rule that recurs every week for ten weeks.
  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule();

  var event = cal.createAllDayEventSeries(title, start, recurrence, {
      description : desc,
      location : loc
  });
};
```

Comment: Have you made sure that the calendar is shared with anyone filling the form? Since the script has to be authorized, and the submission of the form occurs form an account, they must have permission to access the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I created a form and tested with the following code:

```
// Column data constants
var nameCol = 2;
var birthdayCol = 3;
var descriptionCol = 4;
var locationCol = 4;
var calendarId = '[id]@group.calendar.google.com';

/* Send Confirmation Email with Google Forms */

function Initialize() {
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i in triggers) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
  }

  ScriptApp.newTrigger("CreateCalendarEvent")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}

function createEvent() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = ss.getDataRange();
  var lr = rows.getLastRow();
  var start = ss.getRange(lr,birthdayCol,1,1).getValue();
  start.setHours(0);
  start.setMinutes(00);

  var title = ss.getRange(lr,nameCol,1,1).getValue() + " Birthday";
  var desc = ss.getRange(lr,descriptionCol,1,1).getValue();
  var loc = ss.getRange(lr,locationCol,1,1).getValue();

  var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addYearlyRule();

  Logger.log("accessing calendar");
  var externalCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  externalCalendar.createAllDayEventSeries(title, start, recurrence,         {
      description : desc,
      location : loc
  });
}

function getRelativeDate(daysOffset, hour) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + daysOffset);
  date.setHours(hour);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  date.setMilliseconds(0);
  return date;
}

function CreateCalendarEvent(e) {
  try {
    Logger.log("creating event");
    createEvent();
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.toString());
  }

}
```

This sets a trigger function when the form is submitted, make sure that you change the value of the calendar id to the one provided by your calendar.